# JSON Parsing in Snowflake - Square Brackets At Start

Tags: sql, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to parse out some JSON files in snowflake.  In this case, I'd like to extract the "gift card" from the line that has "fulfillment_service": "gift_card".  I've had success querying one dimensional JSON data, but this - with the square brackets - is confounding me.

Here's my simple query - I've created a small table called "TEST_WEEK"

```
select line_items:fulfillment_service
from TEST_WEEK
, lateral flatten(FULFILLMENTS:line_items) line_items;
```

Hopefully this isn't too basic a question.  I'm very new with parsing JSON.

Thanks in advance!

Here's the start of the FULLFILLMENTS field with the info I want to get at.

```
[
  {
    "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid://shopify/Fulfillment/2191015870515",
    "created_at": "2020-08-10T14:54:38Z",
    "id": 2191015870515,
    "line_items": [
      {
        "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid://shopify/LineItem/5050604355635",
        "discount_allocations": [],
        "fulfillable_quantity": 0,
        "fulfillment_service": "gift_card",
        "fulfillment_status": "fulfilled",
        "gift_card": true,
        "grams": 0,
        "id": 5050604355635,
        "name": "Gift Card - $100.00",
        "origin_location": {
          "address1": "100 Indian Road",
          "address2": "",
          "city": "Toronto",
          "country_code": "CA",
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can use two lateral flatten to process values in line_items array:

Sample table:

```
create table TEST_WEEK( FULFILLMENTS variant ) as
select parse_json(
'[
  {
    "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid://shopify/Fulfillment/2191015870515",
    "created_at": "2020-08-10T14:54:38Z",
    "id": 2191015870515,
    "line_items": [
      {
        "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid://shopify/LineItem/5050604355635",
        "discount_allocations": [],
        "fulfillable_quantity": 0,
        "fulfillment_service": "gift_card",
        "fulfillment_status": "fulfilled",
        "gift_card": true,
        "grams": 0,
        "id": 5050604355635,
        "name": "Gift Card - $100.00",
        "origin_location": {
          "address1": "100 Indian Road",
          "address2": "",
          "city": "Toronto",
          "country_code": "CA"
      }
      }
      ]
  }
]');
```

Sample query:

```
select s.VALUE:fulfillment_service 
from TEST_WEEK, 
lateral flatten( FULFILLMENTS ) f,
lateral flatten( f.VALUE:line_items ) s;
```

The output:

```
+-----------------------------+
| S.VALUE:FULFILLMENT_SERVICE |
+-----------------------------+
| "gift_card"                 |
+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: OMG - That's awesome.  Thanks so much.  You nailed it.  I see how you did it too, had two layers of "flattening" to do.  VERY much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Those square brackets indicate that you have an array of JSON objects in your `FULLFILLMENTS` field. Unless there is a real need to have an array of objects in one field you should have a look at the `STRIP_OUTER_ARRAY` property of the `COPY` command. An example can be found [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/semistructured-considerations.html#data-size-limitations) in the Snowflake documentation:

```sql
copy into <table>
from @~/<file>.json
file_format = (type = 'JSON' strip_outer_array = true);
```

Comment: I tried this SimonD, but Fulfillments is just one field of a few dozen in the data.  Sounds like the right way to go if loading in a JSON file from scratch though.

Answer (score 0):

In case others are stuck with same data issue (all json data in one array), I have this solution:

```
select f.VALUE:fulfillment_service::string
from TEST_WEEK, 
lateral flatten( FULFILLMENTS[0].line_items ) f;
```

With this, you just grab the first element of the array (which is the only element).

If you have nested array elements, just add this to the lateral flatten:

```
, RECURSIVE => TRUE, mode => 'array'
```